# How to append block to addto container

Tags: magento2, blocks, frontend

I have a relatively straightforward module in Magento 2 for adding some extra functionality to the **addto** area on the product view page.

I wanted to append my own custom block after the **product.info.addto** block via a layout file, like so:

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <block
                class="VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Product"
                name="product.info.anyname"
                template="VENDOR_MODULE::test.phtml"
                after="product.info.addtocart" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

with my template test.phtml file being a simple echo for now:

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/templates/test.phtml

```
<?php echo 'LA TREY: '; ?>
```

after enabling module, and running the `di:upgrade`, `compile` and `cache clear` `php bin/magento` commands, I go to my catalog product view page and no change. My "La Trey" isn't there.

So I thought I could win by copying the layout/catalog_product/view.xml file to the theme's Magento_Catalog folder - but again, after running the commands - nothing.

How do I get my block to show after the addto container on the catalog product view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `XML` file content with below code.

> app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
                <block
                    class="VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Product"
                    name="product.info.anyname"
                    template="VENDOR_MODULE::test.phtml"
                    after="product.info.addtocart" />
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

After updating this please run below command once..

> php bin/magento cache:flush

**Output**

[image]

Hope this will work!

Comment: Did you updated above content in your XML file ?

Comment: Clear Magento cache once and try

Comment: Also please check your module is enabled or not? If you've added above files in your module then please verify it once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113245/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-treybake).

Comment: Seems fixing that block class issue didn't resolve it - you able to .zip up your plugin and send it over? I'll see if it works - if it doesn't, might be a problem with the theme

Comment: Okay sure. I will add that here within few mins

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qFvSJk53hlhH75gUfVlibWrf5Z47Vind/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks :) (spacer for comment req.)

Comment: resorted back to original theme and it didn't work either :S not sure what's up, what M version you on?

Comment: I am using 2.3.5-p1